# Can't parse simple code using ANTLR 3 with C#

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

Given the gramar

```
grammar T;

options
{
    k=4;
  language=CSharp3;     
  TokenLabelType=CommonToken; 
  output=AST;   
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;  
}

tokens 
{
  LPAREN = '(';
  RPAREN = ')';
  LBRACK = '{';
  RBRACK = '}';
}

fragment
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' |'\r' )+ { $channel = Hidden; } ;

public program: CLASSDEF+ EOF!   ;

CLASSDEF: 'class' ID LBRACK
       RBRACK     ;
```

This produces a lexer and a parser which I use as follows

```
using System;
using Antlr.Runtime;
using Antlr.Runtime.Tree;

namespace compiler
{
  internal class Program2
  {
    public static void Main(string[]arg)
    {
      ANTLRStringStream Input = new ANTLRStringStream(@"class foo 
{ 
}");
      TLexer lex = new TLexer(Input);
      Console.WriteLine("errors:" + lex.NumberOfSyntaxErrors);
      CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
      TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);

      var parsed = parser.program();
      Console.WriteLine("errors: " + parser.NumberOfSyntaxErrors);
      CommonTree tree = parsed.Tree;


      Console.WriteLine("type:" + tree.Type);
      Console.WriteLine("text:" + tree.Text);
      Console.WriteLine("children:" +tree.ChildCount);
      Console.WriteLine(tree.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(tree.ToStringTree());

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

When running this code I get 0 lex errors and 1 parse error

result

```
errors:0
errors: 1
type:0
text:{
}
children:0
<error: {
}>
<error: {
}>
```

Questions!

1. I thought ANTLR was supposed to give intelligent error messages, yet I fail to find out whats wrong
2. Am I missing code to improve on the error messages?

Comment: Would it fix things if you defined a separate token for the keyword `class`? Just a hunch but I think the lexer is confusing it for an identifier which which would be a syntax error according to the grammar.

Comment: I had the same feeling, yet looking at other gramars, I see they don't do that. Also changing the gramar to "CLASSDEF: 'class' WS ID WS LBRACK RBRACK;" did not change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made `CLASSDEF` a lexer rule (in other words: a single token), which is incorrect. When the lexer stumbles upon input like `"class X"`, it cannot create a `CLASSDEF` token because there's a space between `"class"` and `"X"` (and no, the `WS` token will not help you with this since `CLASSDEF` is a lexer rule).

In other words: make `CLASSDEF` a parser rule instead (and remove `fragment` from `ID`!):

```
grammar T;

options
{
  language=CSharp3;     
  output=AST; 
}

tokens 
{
  CLASS  = 'class';
  LPAREN = '(';
  RPAREN = ')';
  LBRACK = '{';
  RBRACK = '}';
}

public program
 : class_def+ EOF!
 ;

class_def
 : CLASS ID LBRACK RBRACK
 ;

ID
 : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
 ;

WS
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' |'\r' )+ { $channel = Hidden; } 
 ;
```

Now parsing input like `"class foo { }"` will produce the following parse:

[image]

Comment: That worked great! However, I still need to better handle error situations such as parsing the string "class foo {" I've only found out how to print <mismatched token: [@5,11:11='<EOF>',<-1>,1:11], resync=class foo{>  which isn't all that helpful. How about telling the expected character? I got that message from doing Console.WriteLine(tree.ToString())

Comment: @CarloV.Dango, producing decent error messages is an art in itself. ANTLR can't simply print the expected character it expects since it doesn't need to be a single character. However, the Java target will produce a more meaningful error for the invalid input `"class foo {"`: *"mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting RBRACK"*. The fact that the CSharp3 produces a less descriptive error message is not something I can help you with. Also see this Wiki entry: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Error+reporting+and+recovery